# Change Language/Resource programmatically w/ WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a DropDown (using MahApps if that is important) that I'd like to use to switch the language "on the fly" in my program.

**Language Class**

```
namespace SAM
{
    public class Language
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Culture { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Change Language**

```
private void DropLanguage_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Language lang = DropLanguage.SelectedItem as Language;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang.Culture);
}
```

I have all my strings as resources in `Resources.resx` (default) and `Resources.en.resx` (english)

**3 issues I don't understand**

- When selecting "englisch" from the dropdown, the language does not change immediately but when I click sth. else, e.g. "close" (it asks "sure?"), the language has changed.
- Strings that are directly in the .xaml file like `<TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Config_HeaderBar_Find_Speaker}" />` do not get updated at all.
- Bonus: How would I switch back to the default language, as `new CultureInfo(lang.Culture);` expects one parameter and for the default I have `Culture = null` (as the Resources.resx has nothing in it's name). Changing the file to `Resources.default.resx` messes with my code a lot...

Answer (score 3):

I tried to solve similar problem. The simplest solution for me was to move all Window content to UserControl and creating interface for window with method refreshLanguage(). Then I call from model:

```
private void SetLanguage(string cultureName)
    {
        var cul = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Properties.Resources.Culture = cul;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cul;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cul;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cul;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cul;
        InitializeHamburgerMenu();
        MainWindowView.RegreshLanguage();
        RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
    }
```

And RefreshLanguage in Window looks like:

```
 public void RegreshLanguage()
    {
        GlobalUserControl content = new GlobalUserControl("Views/SettingsPage.xaml");
        ContentPresenter_GlobalUserControl.Content = content;
    }
```

In my case, UserControl provides navigation, so I passed last navigated URI as parameter. So, if you need to preserve state you can pass it as parameter to new UserControl. *Recreating usercontrol cause all strings to reload without window recreation.* Maybe good idea would be to call `GC.Collect();` here, but depends on your scenario.

About default neutral culture. For me works to call `SetLanguage("")`.

Comment: To me this `Properties.Resources.Culture = cul;` was the missing piece, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

and
   `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`

In order to set these valuse use the static method

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String langCode)
```

where some examples of the parameter langCode are the following strings

```
"de-DE"
"en-US"
```

etc.

more info at

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yck8b540(v=vs.110).aspx

So, overall these lines of code sould work for change in German Language:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
```